# How to keep downloaded file (from FTP) timestamp with R?

Tags: r, download, ftp

I am currently trying to download files over FTP (with R), but I want to keep the source timestamp (last modified date).

I know that download.file (from {base} R) can be used with some extras and I saw on the web that `-R` or `--remote-time` should do the trick. But the code I have written does keep the modified date as the date (and time) of download.

```
download.file(url = "ftp://ftp.datasus.gov.br/dissemin/publicos/SIASUS/200801_/Dados/ABAC1502.dbc",
          destfile = "C:/LocalPath/ABAC1502.dbc",
          quiet = T,
          mode = 'wb',
          method = "libcurl",
          extra = "--remote-time")
```

Am I missing something here?

I have also tried it on other FTP servers with no success.

More details: RStudio v0.99.484, R v3.3.1 (x64), OS Windows 7 Enterprise SP1

Comment: try `method="curl"` vs `method="libcurl"`

Comment: @hrbrmstr Changing to `method="curl"` trows two errors: **error 127** and **download nonzero exit status**

Comment: I think that means the `curl` binary isn't on the system `PATH` which is not surprising since it's Windows and unlikely to be installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**

I knew this had to be built in and found it separated from the `utils::file.…` operations all the way over in the `base::Sys…` operations:

```
Sys.setFileTime(path, time)
```

`¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Though, why this hasn't been expanded to enable setting of `actime` (access time) and `modtime` (modification time) separately is beyond me. *Access* explicitly means the last time the contents of a file was examined. *Modification* means the time the contents of a file was changed (and there are POSIX rules for what constitutes each from a sys call perspective.

I felt compelled to update the answer with more the authoritative solution (though mine is more in the spirit of the POSIX definitions despite not using `utimensat` — which isn't available on most systems). Just remember that with the built-in solution, you're clobbering both access and modify vs just modify.

---

I couldn't get that site to load and I think your problem is solved with the switch to `curl` from `libcurl` in `extra`, but this is a more generic solution (tested on macOS & Windows) that I tested with a known working FTP site:

```
library(curl)
library(Rcpp)
library(inline)

h <- new_handle()
handle_setopt(h, filetime=TRUE, verbose=TRUE) # verbose is just for my debugging
h <- curl_fetch_disk("ftp://ftp.ngdc.noaa.gov/STP/SOLAR_DATA/AIRGLOW/IGYDATA/abst5270",
                      "abst5270", h)

h$modified
## [1] "1999-10-22 18:59:10 EDT"

as.numeric(h$modified)
## [1] 940633150

set_modtime <- rcpp(sig=c(path="character", ts="integer"), body=
" struct stat f_stat;
  struct utimbuf ftp_time;
  std::string file_path = as<std::string>(path);
  long file_ts = as<long>(ts);
  if (stat(file_path.c_str(), &f_stat) >= 0) {
    ftp_time.actime = f_stat.st_atime;
    ftp_time.modtime = file_ts;
    utime(file_path.c_str(), &ftp_time);
  }
", includes=c("#include <time.h>", "#include <utime.h>", "#include <sys/stat.h>"))

# Changes it to way back in the past
invisible(set_modtime("abst5270", as.numeric(h$modified)))

# Changes it back to right now
invisible(set_modtime("abst5270", as.numeric(Sys.time())))
```

It would need some extra checking and exception handling in a package but this shld work fine in a script.

NOTE that you have to use either a full path or accessible working relative path (that may be obvious, but I wanted to make sure it was explained).

Comment: Works like a charm. Outstanding solution, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

On a side note, check datasus function in http://github.com/ajdamico/lodown/. It might be useful.